# Geo-Nodes: How to display specific vertices in spreadsheet?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertices, spreadsheet

I would like to mark a vertex in the 3d preview and know its exact values/coordinates. Is there a way to mark a specific vertex or a selection of vertices in the 3d preview and tell Blender to highlight them in the Spreadsheet? In the screenshot I did this manually by searching its coordinates. But with more complex meshes this is certainly not the most effective way to do.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using *viewer* node:

[image]

You can mark a specific point by *store named attribute*, then see it by connecting a *named attribute* node into a *viewer* node